# What can I do if I have a feature idea that was already requested, but the author removed the suggestion in the meantime?

Tags: discussion, meta, deleted-questions, feature-request-process

I've come up with a feature suggestion for the Stack Exchange engine. After searching the site to ensure my suggestion wasn't already requested, I found an existing post requesting the same thing. The post received a positive reception, and contained (in my view) a strong argument for implementing the feature (it's not the case as in my [prior question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/380482/what-can-i-do-if-i-have-a-good-argument-for-a-feature-change-but-theres-alread)).

In order to try and get the feature change done, I decided to [follow my own advice](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/306398/377214), which is to upvote, edit, or answer with additional arguments as first resorts. The argument in the question was strong, but the question had some grammar, spelling, and/or formatting issues, so I opted to edit it to fix those issues and make the argument clearer. I didn't want to post a duplicate question, and I didn't have much to add in an answer.

However, shortly after I made my edit, the author deleted the question.

I really believe the suggestion is a good idea, but I don't want to repost a deleted question in its prior form. (The feature request already made a strong argument for implementing it and I don't have much to add.)

What can I do to try and get the feature implemented?

One idea is to post the same question with the same argument, but in my own phrasing. After all, if I or someone else were to search for the same suggestion *today*, the deleted question wouldn't come in the search results, which would nullify the second sentence of this question and allow the question to be asked as a clean suggestion. However, a moderator of this site says it's [not a good idea to do so](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/358147/377214), if you're *aware* of a prior deleted post that asks for the same thing:

> Sonic, in the comments, mentions wanting to repost a self-deleted feature request. There's no mention of that post needing serious editing or the original being off-topic. I do not think posts should be reposted without significant changes or improvements. Instead, users with sufficient privileges can vote to undelete such posts.

There are some disadvantages to trying to push for the prior question to be undeleted, though:

- If the author is an active member of the site, there's nothing stopping them from simply re-deleting the question once it gets undeleted. In that case, it would be even harder as I'd have to find three others to vote to undelete (as one can only vote to undelete a post once), which would require 50% more effort than the initial undelete action (as I'd have to find three others to vote, not just two more aside from me).

  Sure, I could be quick and post an answer, but I'd have to add an additional argument for the answer to be valid, and it'd have to be upvoted (the author can delete again in the meantime before it gets an upvote), and that would nullify the point of undeleting (if I had an additional argument, which I don't as the post's argument is already strong, I could just repost as the quote says). I could also resort to more backhanded means and post an intentional duplicate which I then self-close, preventing the author from deleting as there's now a question closed as a duplicate of that, but that's obviously gaming the system (plus that block can be [worked around](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353323/377214)).
- Undeleting the question may go against the wishes of the author. Perhaps they've changed their mind about the suggestion, or no longer care for it to be implemented, and so don't want to have themselves attributed as the "main" person arguing for it. While there are other community members who agree with the suggestion (and have expressed their opinion by voting it up), the author may genuinely want to retract their support for the suggestion, and undeleting the question would go against their wish.

Additionally, in some cases, reposting a question in its exact prior form has been approved by staff, such as [if the original was automatically deleted as an abandoned question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/310266/377214). However, in this case, it was the author who deleted the question (and abandoned questions aren't deleted on meta sites anyway).

Again, what can I do to try and get a feature request asked by someone who deleted their suggestion implemented?

Comment: Is there a link to the deleted post? I realise that it's only viewable by 10K users but that's a fairly large number on MSE.  And could you say **what the feature request is, please?** The Original Poster, who is currently active, could explain *why* they wanted to delete their post and say if they are reconsidering.

Comment: Please provide the number of upvotes and downvotes that the now-deleted request received. That *some* users agreed with it could suggest that it was not a very popular request.

Comment: @Mari-LouAСлаваУкраїні I don't wish to provide a direct link to the question here because I don't want the discussion to be solely about it. I can tell you the following things, though: 1. the question has a [Wilson rating](https://stackapps.com/q/8561/27674) of 66.7%, 2. the author deleted their post for "political" reasons, as SE was still in the long process of recovering from scandals that hit it a while prior, and 3. their bio still states they don't wish to contribute to SE's betterment (despite they having changed their username), which likely means they prefer it remain deleted.

Comment: You could (ask a mod to) reach out to them, to see if they are willing to dissociate themselves from the post.

Comment: There already is a post discussing reposting deleted posts, as you are already aware! We don't need different questions for each possible type of question MSE may have. If you disagree with the answers there, write your own but do it in the right place: the already existing question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> “I do not think posts should be reposted without significant changes or improvements. Instead, users with sufficient privileges can vote to undelete such posts.”

That's a valid *opinion* from one moderator, but it's still an opinion, no rule is mentioned prohibiting a user from posting a new question. No rule impedes a user who has no prior knowledge of a Feature Request posted, that may have received some consensus but whose author later decided to delete, to make a later request. And how would a *new* contributor ever know? Deleted posts are viewable by moderators and 10K users, so even a relatively established user (1k) would be entirely ignorant (in the best sense of the word) of the issue.

In order for a questioner to delete their post, there is one important condition: there must be no upvoted answers. So it's probable that the original questioner deleted their FQ because it did not generate a response from the company. If the OP, in this case, Sonic the Anonymous Hedgehog, reposts a FQ basically repeating the same arguments in favour maybe they will be luckier.

I cannot find any guidelines on the help center which forbids the practice. It is only when a user takes a screenshot or cites a brief passage from a ***post deleted by a mod** and **flagged as being spam or offensive*** does the questioner or answerer incur the risk of being suspended.

**This is clearly not the case here.**

Comment: I definitely agree, and that's my point of view here. The whole reason this was a question is due to the mod comment quoted.

Comment: Also, even 10k+ users may not know, since they can't search for deleted posts.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymous yes, I was going to add that reflection then decided against it. How can users **undelete** a post if they don't know what it is? One way is to post on the meta site asking users to cast their votes to undelete. Which I have done on EL&U in the past [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10493/deleted-upvoted-and-popular-question-why) and [here](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15296/question-deleted-in-2011-is-on-topic-in-2022), and helps explains why in the comments I asked what the FR was.

Comment: Asking for undelete votes is something I considered, but decided against as the author could just override them again immediately, which invalidates the work of the undelete voters as they can't vote again (anymore).

Comment: @SonictheA  When was the post deleted? When a user is absent from a site for several years, it's a safe bet that they will not care. BTW in the 2nd link, the question was deleted by a former moderator. Once that person no longer held that position, users could vote to undelete the Q, which we did. And rather successfully too I might add.

Comment: It was deleted a year after the big scandal season of late 2019. They're still an active member of the site, having been seen this month.

Comment: It is impossible for users to close a question for being a duplicate of a deleted post. If no answers were posted on the older FR, and you feel you can offer better arguments then post your request. If the author of their own self-deleted post objects (but why should they??) they have several options, which I'm not going to list here.

Answer (score 4):

> but I don't want to repost a deleted question in its prior form.

Why? I see no reason to avoid reposting something that was deleted willingly by its author. The OP chose to delete, it's their choice, and being feature request about SE network, it got nothing to do with them personally.

> One idea is to post the same question with the same argument, but in my own phrasing

Yes, that would be ideal in my opinion. That's my opinion and sadly  (for me), the site moderators have the last say, but I stand behind my opinion and honestly can't see the reasoning behind disallowing posting a deleted feature request again. For all we know, the OP might have done it on a whim, without any real reason. It's unfair towards the rest of the people to lose useful feature request over that.

Comment: Well, I also saw no reason avoiding it either, until the moderator recommended against so. The whole reason why this is a question is because of that comment.

Comment: @Sonic that's fair, and I disagree with that moderator.

Comment: Also, speaking of their deletion reason: their username was "Goodbye Stack Exchange" at the time of deletion, and their bio stated (and still states) they don't wish to contribute to SE's betterment, which tells me the deletion was for "political" reasons due to SE's scandals at the time.